# Smoke coming out of Arduino Uno R4 Minima

Tags: arduino-uno-r4-wifi

My Arduino Uno R4 Minima started smoking after connecting to a computer. I disconnected it and visually checked it and I saw this bubble as shown on this photo.

[image: Photo of my Uno R4]

Can I recover my Uno from this to still use it or do I have to throw it away?

Comment: Was anything else connected?

Comment: Can the computer still talk to the board? If not, then it's probably dead. You *could* repair it by replacing the IC, if you are handy with a hot air gun. If not, I still wouldn't throw it away, it might be useful for parts.

Comment: did you place the board on top of something metallic?

Comment: did you power the board with an external power supply connected  to the barrel jack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marked IC is burnt. You should complain to the seller and claim warranty. if it is still within the warranty period. If you are very skilled at soldering. You can try to replace the IC.

Comment: If the OP damaged it through misuse then why would the seller be liable?

Answer (score 6):

That's  the buck-converter that connects to the external power supply.

The board should still work when powered by the USB cable.

Remove R11 to isolate the blown circuit if you like.

https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/schematics/ABX00080-schematics.pdf

[image]